# Calling cancelEdit to all cells in a TableView JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am using a custom editable table cell factory that I have been working on for some time. I am currently implementing a functionality to allow single clicking to begin editing.

I have the single click starting the cell edit, however if you click another cell once, the previous doesn't close. My idea was to loop over all cells calling `cancelEdit()` just before opening the clicked cell to editing.

Below is the entire cell class I am using (that works fine with double-click to edit) The section I am working on is in the constructor.

```
public class EditingCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {
    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
        TableView<S> table = this.getTableView();
        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                for(TableColumn<S, ?> col : table.getColumns()) {
                    // cancelEdit() on all cells here
                }
                startEdit();
            }
        });
    }

    public void commit(Object val) {
        commit(val, this.getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableView().getColumns().indexOf(this.getTableColumn()));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public void commit(Object val, int row, int col) {

        // Get the table
        TableView<S> t = this.getTableView();

        // Get the selected row/column
        S selectedRow = t.getItems().get(row);
        if (selectedRow == null)
            return;
        TableColumn<S, ?> selectedColumn = t.getColumns().get(col);

        // Get current property name
        String propertyName = ((PropertyValueFactory) selectedColumn.getCellValueFactory()).getProperty();

        // Create a method name conforming to java standards ( setProperty )
        propertyName = ("" + propertyName.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);

        // Try to run the update
        try {

            // Type specific checks - could be done inside each
            // setProperty() method
            if (val instanceof Double) {
                Method method = selectedRow.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, double.class);
                method.invoke(selectedRow, (double) val);
            }
            if (val instanceof String) {
                Method method = selectedRow.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, String.class);
                method.invoke(selectedRow, (String) val);
            }
            if (val instanceof Integer) {
                Method method = selectedRow.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, int.class);
                method.invoke(selectedRow, (int) val);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // CommitEdit for good luck
        commitEdit((T) val);

        TableUtils.Refresh(t, t.getItems());

    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        String val = "0.0";
        if (!textField.getText().equals(""))
            val = "" + Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

        setText(NumberUtils.roundTo2(NumberUtils.parseDouble(val)) + "");
        setGraphic(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText("");
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(NumberUtils.roundTo3(NumberUtils.parseDouble(getString())) + "");
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());

        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                if (!arg2) {
                    if (textField.getText().equals(""))
                        commit(0.0);
                    else {
                        double val = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                        commit(val);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                textField.setText("" + getItem());
                cancelEdit();
                event.consume();
            }
            // Navigate up and down in table
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

                TableView<S> table = getTableView();
                int row = table.getEditingCell().getRow();

                // Commit changes
                if (textField.getText().equals(""))
                    commit(0.0);
                else {
                    double val = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                    commit(val);
                }

                // Do move
                if (event.isShiftDown())
                    table.edit(row - 1, getTableColumn());
                else {
                    table.edit(row + 1, getTableColumn());
                }

            }

            // Move left and right in table
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                TableView<S> table = getTableView();
                int row = table.getEditingCell().getRow();

                // Save changes
                if (textField.getText().equals(""))
                    commit(0.0);
                else {
                    double val = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                    commit(val);
                }

                ArrayList<TableColumn<S, ?>> cols = new ArrayList<TableColumn<S, ?>>();
                int index = 0;
                for (TableColumn<S, ?> c : table.getColumns()) {
                    if (c.isVisible() && c.isEditable())
                        cols.add(c);
                    if (c == getTableColumn())
                        index = cols.size() - 1;
                }

                // Do move
                if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                    try {
                        TableColumn<S, ?> prevCol = cols.get(index - 1);
                        table.edit(row, prevCol);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        TableColumn<S, ?> nextCol = cols.get(index + 1);
                        table.edit(row, nextCol);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>((Change c) -> {
            String text = c.getText();

            TableView<S> table = getTableView();
            if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() == 0) {
                return c;
            }
            TablePosition pasteCellPosition = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
            int clipRow = 0;
            int clipCol = 0;

            String curCellText = text;

            if (text.contains("\t") || text.contains("\n")) {

                StringTokenizer row = new StringTokenizer(text, "\n");
                boolean hasRun = false;

                while (row.hasMoreTokens() || !hasRun) {
                    String r = row.nextToken();
                    StringTokenizer col;
                    if (r != null)
                        col = new StringTokenizer(r, "\t");
                    else
                        col = new StringTokenizer(text, "\t");

                    hasRun = true;
                    clipCol = 0;

                    while (col.hasMoreTokens()) {

                        String content = col.nextToken();

                        if (clipRow == 0 && clipCol == 0) {
                            curCellText = content;
                        }

                        // calculate the position in the table cell
                        int rowTable = pasteCellPosition.getRow() + clipRow;
                        int colTable = pasteCellPosition.getColumn() + clipCol;

                        // Skip hidden columns before current cell
                        for (int i = 0; i < colTable; i++)
                            if (!table.getColumns().get(i).isVisible())
                                colTable++;

                        // Skip hidden columns between current and goal
                        while (!table.getColumns().get(colTable).isVisible()) {
                            if (colTable >= table.getColumns().size())
                                break;
                            colTable++;
                        }

                        // Add row if we reach the end
                        if (rowTable >= table.getItems().size()) {
                            if (table.getItems().get(0) instanceof EditableTableRow)
                                ((EditableTableRow) table.getItems().get(0)).addRowToTable(table);

                            // continue;
                        }
                        if (colTable >= table.getColumns().size()) {

                            continue;
                        }

                        try {
                            double val = Double.parseDouble(content);
                            commit(val, rowTable, colTable);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            try {
                                int val = Integer.parseInt(content);
                                commit(val, rowTable, colTable);
                            } catch (Exception e2) {
                                commit(content, rowTable, colTable);
                            }
                        }

                        clipCol++;
                    }

                    clipRow++;
                }
            }
            c.setText(curCellText);

            return c;
        }));
        textField.requestFocus();
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the [TextFieldTableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) class?

Comment: Main reason - I just now found out that exists..... However, I think I'll keep it as-is because I made a lot of changes to the functionality (such as trimming displayed numbers vs actual numbers and pasting from excel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't iterate over all cells; you have no way of knowing what cells have been created, which represent actual items, etc.

You can call

```
getTableView().edit(-1, null);
```

which will have the effect of canceling editing. (See [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#edit-int-javafx.scene.control.TableColumn-).) It may actually be better just to call

```
getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
```

instead of calling `startEdit()`. This will (should? I haven't tested...) invoke `startEdit()` for you. In other words, do

```
public EditingCell() {
    addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> 
        getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn()));
}
```

As an aside, why do you go to all the trouble of making the cell implementation very general, but then assuming the cell value factory is an instance of `PropertyValueFactory`? Surely you can get the cell observable value with

```
ObservableValue<T> obs = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()));
```

and then just do

```
if (obs instanceof WritableValue) {
    ((WritableValue<?>) obs).setValue(val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the edit, i will try that. I am not familiar with JavaFx too much to know all the best practices yet so I just went with my first working solution. I keep everything very general because I use this table cell on ~20 different tables all with different row classes.

Comment: What is a good way to get the position of my cell I want to call edit on? (in that same constructor where I call `startEdit`)

Comment: `PropertyValueFactory` is kind of legacy and bad practice in and of itself. It was only written as a convenience class before we had lambda expressions, which provide a typesafe way to specify the property for the column with virtually no additional verbosity: `myColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().someProperty());`. To answer your question, though, just use the code I showed: `getIndex()` in a table cell gives the index of the row and `getTableColumn()` gives the table column: those are exactly the parameters `TableView.edit(...)` needs.

Comment: BTW, don't assume the table view is set on the cell when the constructor is invoked: call `getTableView()` in the handler, not directly in the constructor.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, that works exactly as intended. I will also make the change to `PropertyValueFactory` to keep up with conventions. Thanks for the help!